# iptables two eth passing internet, internal lan blocked to the world, how to solve this?

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

dsl modem, linux server, router, couple computers

dsl modem connected > to eth0 at my server
router for sharing internet connection connected to > eth1 at my server

server got mascarade to pass internet connection to eth1 > router, lan computers

now i have problem, because all my lan computers are blocked by linux server to access several services, for example ftp.

i need to unblock serveral ports in linux server how i would do that, any example would be gratefull, i am bit nob at iptables itself.

if i connect from outside of my network, with different provider i have access to ftp ect..

Answer (score 0):

Do `iptables -L OUTPUT -n --line-numbers` which will show you all the rules for OUTPUT and find the appropriate rules that block port 21,etc.
Then do something like `iptables -D OUTPUT line-number` otherwise do a `iptables -F` which will DELETE all rules from iptables and try set your own.

Most definitely there is a script somewhere in /etc/init.d or /etc/rc.d that sets the rules
on boot depending on your distro.

Comment: Does iptables refers to my two interfaces eth0 and eth1 ?, i dumped my iptables rules, could you look ?, i tryed your first command and it does not print anything at all, why?. As to rewriting firewall you where right, after i do reboot iptables are rewriten, i got centos 5.3 distro, and there is my iptables output: http://pastebin.com/dB69cySp